# What is initial velocity here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

If I am having a graph of displacement versus time and at time = 0 second, the displacement of an object is 10 metres.

I need to know: what is its initial velocity?

Is it 10 m/s?

(Note that the average velocity is given: 20 m/s)

Also, its a rectilinear motion and has constant (0$m/s^2$ ) acceleration throughout.

Comment: The initial velocity may be 0. Graph will start from y axis at point 10m instead of 0.

Comment: @WrichikBasu Yes, graph starts at y=10m, but why initial velocity may be 0?

Comment: See, that was a guess. I believe that your question is unclear, and you need to put up more info on what type of motion you're analysing and similar facts. On your current question, I cannot say more. Others will surely help you, if they can.

Comment: @WrichikBasu Is the question clear now? Or more info needed??

Comment: Is it possible to upload a picture of the graph?

Answer (score 1):

If the acceleration is $0$ then the velocity does not change and the instantaneous velocity is the average velocity, i.e. $20m/s$. The graph of $x$ as a function of $t$ will be a line with slope $20$, i.e. $x=20 t + x_0$, and going through the point $(x,t)=(10,0)$

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that it's a rectilinear motion and given acc=0, this implies that

average velocity = instantaneous velocity

because the body neither accelerates nor decelerates.Only when there is a acc/dec there is a change in velocity. So it's initial velocity = average velocity.